# Android - how to check if user press OK button from AlertDialog

Tags: android

i have AlertDialog consist of two button ok and cancel.

how i can check if user pressed OK and do something

declaring string

```
private String newtext = "";
```

AlertDialog box code

```
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PrintDemo.this);
            builder.setTitle("Title");

            // Set up the input
            final EditText input = new EditText(PrintDemo.this);
            // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            builder.setView(input);

            // Set up the buttons
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    newtext = input.getText().toString();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });


            builder.show();
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Display `Toast` when user press ok

```
 builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                newtext = input.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"OK BUTTON PRESSED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: yes nice solution... i want to reopen same dialogbox if user press cancel.. how i can do that.....

Comment: if you want to still there then just remove dialog.cancel(); and if you want to reopen it then add dialog.show(); after dialog.cancel();

Answer (score 1):

Right there in your `OnClickListener` for the positive button.

When the user clicks the button you've labeled "OK", the `onClick` method in the listener will execute.

```
 builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // do all your stuff here
            }
        });
```

Same goes for detecting if they clicked "Cancel".

It sounds like you're used to a blocking dialog that when you show it, it will return an `int` which you then need to check and see if it was OK or Cancel.  That's not how the Android dialog works.  There is no return value from the dialog that you need to check, all the action happens in those `OnClickListener`s.  It's a bit of a shift in thinking, but if you just give it a try you'll get used to it.

Comment: class ClickEvent implements View.OnClickListener {

Comment: What is it you're trying to have happen?

Comment: } else if (v == btnsearchpre) {

Comment: Maybe you need to modify the question.  There is no "check to see if the user pressed ok."  You just execute the code in the listener when they press ok.  It doesn't get executed until they press ok.

Comment: newtext is getting set when they press OK, but you're not doing anything with that variable so you're not going to see it.  Maybe put it in a toast to confirm it's working, or debug it to see for yourself.

Comment: or can we check if user has input "a" on clicking OK

Comment: Yes, you would do that in the `onClick` method.

Comment: then i will call it by ----    } else if (v == "OK") {

Comment: Revised answer, sounds like you're just not used to this way of doing dialogs.